# Url.Action Does Not Show Data

Tags: model-view-controller, url.action

Im trying to get a string returned from an ActionResult to the view

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetName(string id)
    {
        string returnName;
        returnName = m_DB.UserProfiles.Find(id).FirstName;

        return Content(returnName);
    }
```

View

```
    <li>
       @Url.Action("GetName", "UserProfile", new {id=User.Identity.GetUserId()})

    </li>
```

When I run , it just shows this in the view

/UserProfile/GetName/7781341a-ab1b-4b1d-b75b-853376690bf4

All I want is  to show user's first name. What am I doing wrong? Please help. I appreciate your contribution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method you are looking for is `@Html.RenderAction` or `@Html.Action`

```
 @Html.RenderAction("GetName", "UserProfile", new {id=User.Identity.GetUserId()})
```

or

```
 @Html.Action("GetName", "UserProfile", new {id=User.Identity.GetUserId()})
```

`@Url.Action` takes the parameters you provide it with and builds a url while `@Html.RenderAction` renders the result of the action inline in the view where it is called.

Comment: Hi, Thanks heaps for the quick response. However when I add your code it gives an error saying 

Can not convert implicitly 'void' to 'object'

Comment: Can not convert implicitly 'void' to 'object'

Comment: @RandikaWijekoon Trying using the second one Html.Action

Comment: @RandikaWijekoon Glad it worked :) I'm sure you'll get the hang of it soon enough.